# How to multiple sshconnection in same bash script via sshpass

Tags: bash, scripts, sshpass

I'm a bit beginner on linux.
Let's imagine a scenario like this.
I have 4 different linux machines and these 4 machines have different scripts.
From to an another machine, I want to connect to these 4 different machines in the same script and run the scripts on this machines.

I created such a method in my head.

But I am not sure how to make ssh connection to 4 different machines at the same time. I think it should disconnect the ssh connection after it is done on one machine.

Do you think something like this will work or what can I do to make it work?

```
  #!/bin/bash
  variableA="$1"

  SSHPASS='mypassforsshcon'

  sshpass -p $SSHPASS ssh user@xxx.1 /home/admin/1.sh $variableA
  sshpass -p $SSHPASS ssh user@xxx.2 /home/admin/2.sh $variableA
  sshpass -p $SSHPASS ssh user@xxx.3 /home/admin/3.sh $variableA
  sshpass -p $SSHPASS ssh user@xxx.4 /home/admin/4.sh $variableA
```

I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try running them in the background by adding `&&` at the end of every command, that way they will execute at the same time (almost) something like this

```
  #!/bin/bash
  variableA="$1"

  SSHPASS='mypassforsshcon'

  sshpass -p $SSHPASS ssh user@xxx.1 /home/admin/1.sh $variableA &&
  sshpass -p $SSHPASS ssh user@xxx.2 /home/admin/2.sh $variableA &&
  sshpass -p $SSHPASS ssh user@xxx.3 /home/admin/3.sh $variableA &&
  sshpass -p $SSHPASS ssh user@xxx.4 /home/admin/4.sh $variableA &&
```